# Open Sharepoint Document with Custom Action

Tags: custom-actions

I have a List (called Enquiry) with a workflow that creates a new Document in a Document Library (called Records) with the same Title and ID as the List Item’s Title and ID.  To illustrate:

Item in List called “Enquiry”
Title: EnquiryOne
ID: 1

Workflow runs on creation of item to Create document in Records:

Title: EnquiryOne
ID: 1

What I would like to be able to do is have a way of opening the Document from the Item DispForm.aspx

I have added a custom action button to my DispForm.aspx, and set it to Navigate to URL.

Is there a way of setting the URL to dynamically link to the appropriate URL or ID?

For example, by setting the URL to be:

.../Records/DispForm.aspx?ID={ItemId}

I know that this doesn’t work, so was wondering if there is a way to open the right link using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document library you also need to create one new column that will be lookup of Inquiry list.

**How to display that document link on Display page of inquiry**

Below video has complete tutorial of what you are trying to do

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYU8bQ6Sw8I

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Exactly what I needed